# Text won't enter into the database!

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
$log = "Pooled a football league game";
$database->adminActLog($log);
```

The adminActLog....

```
function adminActLog($act)
{
    $q = "INSERT INTO ".TBL_ADMIN_ACTIVITY." VALUES (NULL, '$_SESSION[id]', '$act', DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 HOUR))";
    mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
}
```

The field that I am trying to enter this into is varchar(255).

It's just not entering the database? The other fields are being populated?

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but please read about SQL injection before you go any further: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection.

Comment: Is TBL_ADMIN_ACTIVITY a constant? You don't specify that it is, and if it isn't, then you have a syntax error.

Comment: What gets reported in the error log? (Assuming you are running this on a web server and can't see the errors output to the command line directly).

Comment: What's the value of $act that you're trying to store? Has it been properly escaped?

Comment: Always check for return values of `mysql_query` to get an information about its success and possible errors..

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but you should be escaping that $act variable using `mysql_real_escape_string`. Though it's your code, never go on the assumption that `adminActLog` will never be passed a value with a single quote in it.

Comment: 1. Use [PDO](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and prepared statements instead of `mysql_*()` interface. 2. What does `mysql_error()` return?

Comment: can you check TBL_ADMIN_ACTIVITY with `echo TBL_ADMIN_ACTIVITY;`

Answer (score -1):

```
" VALUES (NULL, '$_SESSION[id]'
```

doesn't make sense at all; you want:

```
" VALUES (NULL, '".$_SESSION[id]."'
```

As it stands, you're trying to insert the raw string "$_SESSION[id]" into the 2nd column. It's probably type-incompatible which is causing an error.

Comment: @Crozin - weird, I could swear I've done that countless times before and it's failed. Is that PHP-version-dependant?

Comment: Not sure but as far as I remember this is well supported for a really long time. However as I said that's a horrible code and should be replaced by something like `"... {$_SESSION['id']} ..."`

Comment: -1. You're pretending that PHP interpolation doesn't exist. It might not always be a great idea, but it certainly does exist and using it here is not causing the issue.

Comment: @Tomalek: I'm well aware that, for example, "hello, $first_name" exists, but I didn't realise array values could also interpolate - I could swear I've tried it in the past and it's failed.